# Shouldn't the pwr.r.test on correlation estimate higher n for a higher rho value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, p-value, statistical-power

The `pwr.r.test` in R which uses the arctanh transformation (Fisher's $z$ transformation) relates inversely with the correlation coefficient.  That is, if $r$ is high then $n$ is low.

```
pwr.r.test(n=NULL, r=.7, sig.level=0.01, power=0.99, alternative="two.sided")
```

gives `n = 34.4932`.  Whereas,

```
pwr.r.test(n=NULL, r=.9, sig.level=0.01, power=0.99, alternative="two.sided")
```

gives `n = 13.84951`.

Isn't that counterintuitive? For a higher correlation value, I'd expect more samples. Thus higher $n$ to say that the correlation is significant.

Comment: Why would you expect higher n when the correlation is stronger (further from the null value of 0)?

Comment: Well I'm trying to measure the sig. of the cor. , thus I put n==NULL in the pwr.t.test ,
I would expect higher n since the strong cor. might be a false pos.
The stronger the cor. , the more samples should be needed to ascertain the sig.

Answer (score 3):

`pwr.r.test` performs sample size calculation for a correlation test (H0: true correlation = ***0***). The question is: how many samples do I need to detect the anticipated correlation (`r` argument) ? Well, it is harder to detect a correlation of 0.7 than a correlation of 0.9. Hence the larger sample size in the former case.

More info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/vignettes/pwr-vignette.html).

Comment: Sorry i don't get this part - why would a cor of 0.7 be more harder to detect than 0.9 ? Assuming we are sampling our data set , its possible to sample in such a way so as to achieve a weak correlation between 2 variables which is false positive. If we need a strong cor. which is significant enough, you need more samples. 

The same is case when you do a t-test . The more sig and power you choose the higher your N .

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow you....
In a t-test, a difference of 1 is harder to detect than a difference of 10000.
Likewise, a correlation of 0.7 is harder to detect than a correlation of 0.9.